# Is there a Magento 2 PHP Class for Validating URLs

Tags: php, magento2

I just want to know if there is a php class in Magento 2 dedicated to validating url. Perhaps a class I can inject into my constructor and use in the class for URL validation. If there is none, is there a clean way to validate URL using PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's `parse_url()` function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php